# Virtual Network adaptor which is always online

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, vmware

I'm not exactly sure how to word this, so please forgive me for lame wording.

**My situation is this:**

I have 2 identical docking stations, one at home and one at work. I run VMware Workstation 12, and use bridged networking. It works fine at work, but when I come home I have to always be setting up the network again in VMware Virtual Network Editor (because although I use the same port on the dock for the Ethernet cable, apparently its a different hardware ID or something, even though its exactly the same docking station and therefore is registered as a different network adaptor to the one on my work docking station)

**The Ideal Result**

Is there a way of creating a static 'virtual' network adaptor on the host machine, that will take whatever internet connection is available and I can then set this static adaptor up within VMware?

Thanks in advance! Hoping this is the right forum to be posting too.

Running Windows 8.1 Pro X64.